# A question has two solutions when I'm asked to prove one of them

Tags: trigonometry

So the question is

Prove that 
$$\cot^{-1}{\sqrt{1+\sin x}+\sqrt{1-\sin x}\over\sqrt{1+\sin x}-\sqrt{1-\sin x}}={x\over 2};$$

$x$ belongs to $(0,π/4)$.

I simplified using $\sin x=2\sin(x/2)\cos(x/2)$ and $1=\sin^2(x/2)+\cos^2(x/2)$ and I get two answers because the second term in the numerator and denominator can be considered as either $(\sin x-\cos x)^{2}$ or $(\cos x-\sin x)^2$ leading to:

(I) the correct answer $x/2$;

(II) another solution $\cot^{-1}(\tan(x/2))$.

Am I missing something?

Comment: This site uses 
[MathJax formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x\in(0,\pi/4)$ you have $\cos x>\sin x$ so that 
$$\sqrt{(\cos x -\sin x)^2}=\sqrt{(\sin x -\cos x)^2}=\cos x -\sin x.$$

Answer (score 0):

If $ s =\sin x/2 , c = \cos x/2$ it simplifies to $ y= \tan^{-1} (\tan(x/2)) $ and complement..

Since both are correct each valid for its own domain. If the domain is given you need not consider outside the domain for saw-tooth function $y= ( x/2, \pi/2 - x/2)$

[image: SawTooth]